# facebook.stackoverflow.com inbox has wrong links

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

I have a notification in my inbox for something I posted on Stack Overflow. Normally when I view my inbox from a different site the links still point to the right place, but when I view my inbox from facebook.stackoverflow the link goes to facebook.stackoverflow, even though the post is unrelated to facebook. I can still see the answer when I follow the link, but I'm on the facebook subdomain. Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), or was it supposed to be this way?

---

Side point:

When i am accidentally in facebook.so and I want to ask a SO question and then I click on ask a question - it forces me to put a facebook tag!

Comment: Are we talking about the inbox in the StackExchange drop-down or somewhere else?

Comment: @Incognito -- on the stackexchange dropdown, is there any other place to view the inbox?

Comment: It normally shows me an aggregation of all websites, which is why I was confused.

Comment: Just to be clear, was the answer you're talking about posted under a question with a facebook-related tag?

Comment: @PopularDemand -- see update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is intentional.

Once you're on Stack Overflow or Facebook Stack Overflow, we intend for you to stay on there.  All content is available on both domains.

For example:
[Hidden Features of C# (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)
[Hidden Features of C# (Facebook)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c)

The canonical copy is on Stack Overflow.

Think of Facebook Stack Overflow as a view onto vanilla Stack Overflow.  By going there, you've said "I want to see stuff related to Facebook".  We do our best to keep you in that view.

Comment: yes, but then when i am accidentally in facebook.so and I want to ask a SO question and then I click on ask a question - it forces me to put a facebook tag!

Comment: @Neal - the problem there is being accidentally on facebook.so :) ; the inbox is operating correctly.

Comment: but the only reason i was on facebook.so is because i was never redirected to the correct so site...

Comment: @Neal - if you go directly the facbook.so, it is the correct site.  You've said you want to look at a filter on SO by... going to a filtered view of SO.

Comment: then clicking on one of my unrelated answers in the inbox (which has **nothing to do with facebook!)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like any questions available on https://stackoverflow.com/ is also available (and looks quite same) on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/. As an example, http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1311991/latex-avoid-new-paragraph = [LaTeX: Avoid new paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311991/latex-avoid-new-paragraph). (Ah, the inlining of the title for the former seems to work not in the preview, only in the finally rendered post.)

So, these links in your inbox will still work, whether or not you are currently on the facebook-specific domain.

But all tag pages (like http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex compared to [latex](/questions/tagged/latex)), as well as the user lists are only listing questions which also have a facebook tag, which might be a bit confusing - even more as there is no visual distinguisher between both domains.

So I would recommend changing the logo somehow to make it clear that some links are facebook-filtered (and also provide some link to the same page in a non-filtered view).